# BATCH: If choice not equal to, start again

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Trying to set some basic validation in a batch file but keep getting a syntax error. Basically, 3 choices, if anything but 1, 2 or 3 is entered I want to start from beginning.

```
set input=
set /p input=Choice: 
if %input%==1 goto 1
if %input%==2 goto 2
if %input%==3 goto 3
if not %input%==1
if not %input%==2
if not %input%==3
@echo Not a valid choice
goto Start
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the three `if not` statements at all.

```
:start
set input=
set /p input=Choice: 
if %input%==1 goto 1
if %input%==2 goto 2
if %input%==3 goto 3
@REM If you got here, it wasn't 1, 2, or 3
@echo Not a valid choice
goto start

:1
DoWhatever
goto end

:2
DoSecondWhatever
goto end

:3
DoThirdThing

:end
```